# How do I change a boolean to true when a users lands on a certain page?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a boolean field in my DB called `premium`. By default it is set to false, however I want it to change to true if a user lands on a certain page.

I have a PHP background and what I usually would do to make this happen would be this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET premium = true WHERE user_id = $user_id")
```

I want to do the exact same thing as this but, in Rails instead. So, how would I do this?

I tried:

```
execute "UPDATE TABLE `users` SET `premium` = true WHERE user_id = current_user.id"
```

But, that didn't work.

Comment: `"UPDATE users SET premium = true WHERE user_id = $user_id"`... oooOOO? Pending SQL-injection attack?

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby on Rails, for database calls most of the time time you want to use ActiveRecord.

You can find a specific user like this:

```
u1 = User.find(params[:id])
```

Or use the current user and modify it like this:

```
current_user.premium = true
current_user.save!
```

This will also give you all sorts of helpful things like ensuring that the query cannot be SQL injected.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thanks. But, this still hasn't worked could you go into more detail

Comment: What error came up when you tried this? Where did you put this code?

Comment: No errors. It just isn't changing the boolean field in the db to true. I put it in the Application controller as a method and included that method in an erb page

Comment: You shouldn't put these things in the application controller. You could create a separate controller and add this to your routes. Check out a guide on Rails to help point you in the right direction on how to structure your app and use MVP effectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to determine "where" is your user , as you state in your question ("if a user lands on a certain page") , there is a helper :

```
<%- if request.path = "/your_special_path" %>
```